# PHP Mailer: How to parse as parameters the value of a select option

Tags: php, phpmailer

I need to parse as parameter the `$_POST['Country']` inside the function the php mailer function. I take the value of that though javascript with:

```
var country = $("#country").val();
```

How can I parse the parameter of this inside the php script and the body to see select options?
I need to put somewhere in php That value, so far I get 500 internal error.

Html of the inputs:

```
  <select name="countryName" id="country" name="country">
      <option value="cy">Κύπρος</option>
      <option value="gr">Ελλάδα</option>
      <option value="other">άλλη</option>
    </select>
```

then with ajax I do this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../../sendemail.php',
            data: {
                Name: name,
                Email: email,
                message: Message,
                Country : country,

            },
```

Here is the php code:

```
if(empty($_POST['Email'])){
        $_POST['Email']= "";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['Name'])){
        $_POST['Name']= "";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['Subject'])){
        $_POST['Subject']= "";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['message'])){
        $_POST['message']= "";
    }



if (isset($_POST["message"]) && !empty($_POST["message"])) {

 $mymail=smtpmailer("webdominar1@gmail.com",$_POST['Email'], $_POST  ['Name'],
 $_POST['Subject'], $_POST['message']);    


}else{  
    header('Location: http://google.com'); exit();

}



function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can't parse the 'select' input options since only the value of the chosen option is sent through the form.

The `$_POST['Country']` var will have the value of the chosen option of the select input.

> UPDATE :

PHP SIDE :

```
<?php
    $options = json_decode($_POST["country"]);
?>
```

```js
 function sendAjax(){

      // Get the options of select input
        var selectOptions = document.getElementById("country");
 var countries = [];
 for (i = 0; i < selectOptions.length; i++) {
  countries.push(selectOptions.options[i].value);
 }
    // Parse the array with all the options into JSON
 var parsedOptions = JSON.stringify(countries);

    // Send the AJAX request
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '../../sendemail.php',
  data: {
  Country : parsedOptions,
    }
 });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="country" id="country">
     <option value="USA">USA</option>
     <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
     <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
</select>

<button onClick="sendAjax()">Send</button>
```

Comment: yes in the html it has 2 options. I need to take these and print them inside my body to receive in the email the options

Comment: Then i'll recommend using JS to get all the values of the 'select' input and store then in an array. Then parse the array as JSON and pass it through AJAX as a JSON text and then decode the JSON in the php code.

Comment: Is there an easier way? It is just 3 options. I have updated my question

Comment: If you always use the same two options then why send them through the ajax? why not set them as vars in php?

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you more idea about my solution.
If it fits you please set my answer as the chosen answer. Thanks :)

Comment: wtf that is really advanced staff, I doubt I can even copy paste dat :S The problem is mostly with php and how can I retrieve the values and print them inside the body of my email with phpmailer

Comment: I added comments within the code so you'll understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149511/discussion-between-eternal-and-niv-apo).